# Napoleon's Height

Tags: france, napoleon, french-empire

I have heard from some scholars that Napoleon was actually average sized. The only reason everyone thinks he is short is because of the difference in English inches and French inches. Is this true?

Comment: First, welcome to [history.se]! Perhaps you might consider registering your account and become a regular curator. I would strongly suggest reading through the [help] pages, including what to ask and what not to ask.

Comment: If the question is valid (a very similar is at 24 upvotes), no need to downvote, it can be closed duplicate

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary If that was to me, I neither up- nor down-voted this, I only flagged as duplicate

Answer (score -4):

Napolean's height, measured after his death, was 5 feet, 6 inches and 22/45ths of an inch. (The Table Talk and Opinions of Napoleon Buonaparte, 1870).

Napolean, nicknamed in France as the "Little Corporal", was routinely caricatured by British cartoonists as short:

[image: Napolean]

Years later, Hitler got the same treatment.

Comment: this doesn't actually answer his question at all, since hes asking if their was a misrepresentation of his height due to measurement issues. please update with the relative conversions that could cause this confusion as to the OP request.

Comment: @Himarm I updated my answer.

Comment: The confusion and misrepresentation of Napoleon's height can be attributed to a combination of the following:

Napoleon's height was stated to be 5'2 inches. The inches were French rather than British. When converted, it would have been equivalent to 5 feet and 7 British inches which is a respectable height. http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/was-napoleon-as-short-as-common-knowledge-states

Comment: @Himarm I disagree that the French measurement is the source of the stereotype. If you think it is, then why don't you write your competing answer with evidence, instead of just badmouthing my answer?

Comment: I'm not badmouthing your answer, I'm telling you hes asking specifically about the measurements, So you answer has to include something about them, either proving or disproving the validity of his question, but you cant discard the primarily question without even referencing it. if you dont agree that the french measurement is the source of the stereotype you have to actually argue against it.

Comment: this answer is a prime example of why you have 40+ negative score answers, and another 50+ 0 score answers, your providing information, but not what is requested in the question, which is why even though everything you posted is accurate information, it is getting downvoted because its not answering the question.